# 301 redirects of subpages

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns, forwarding

There are lots of questions about these redirects but it didn't worke for me.

We are moving a site to another domain and we would like to redirect all links to the new domain, including sub pages.

I'm using hostgator so I made the 301 redirect from the cPanel but only the front page goes to new domain
        www.etilerprep2go.com --> www.iqworldinc.com
        etilerprep2go.com  --> www.iqworldinc.com

But we also need the subpages to redirect too because of google ranks etc. i mean we want this link
http://www.etilerprep2go.com/egitimlerimiz-etiler-ingilizce-kursu/  should go to http://www.iqworldinc.com/egitimlerimiz-etiler-ingilizce-kursu/

Well I couldn't manage that. at the moment the code is looks like this at the end of htaccess:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.iqworldinc\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

Any advice how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

edit: I managed to do that by adding all the categories and other pages manually as;

```
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on
    RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.iqworldinc.com
    Redirect 301 /hakkimizda-etiler-levent-ingilizce-kursu http://www.iqworldinc.com/hakkimizda-etiler-levent-ingilizce-kursu
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/egitimlerimiz-etiler-ingilizce-kursu/(.*)$ http://www.iqworldinc.com/egitimlerimiz-etiler-ingilizce-kursu
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/etiler-ingilizce-kursu-iletisim/(.*)$ http://www.iqworldinc.com/etiler-ingilizce-kursu-iletisim
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/etiler-ingilizce-kursu-haberler/(.*)$ http://www.iqworldinc.com/etiler-ingilizce-kursu-haberler/
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/etiler-is-ingilizcesi/(.*)$ http://www.iqworldinc.com/etiler-is-ingilizcesi/
    RedirectMatch 301 ^/etiler-ielts-kursu/(.*)$ http://www.iqworldinc.com/etiler-ielts-kursu/
```

But I still wonder is there any way to do all the pages in a codeline.

Answer (score 0):

This will transfer the vistitors and your SEO

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} etilerprep2go.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.iqworldinc.com/$1  [R=301,L]
```

Comment: no it's not working. when i enter
[http://www.etilerprep2go.com/](http://www.etilerprep2go.com/)  it goes to; http://www.etilerprep2go.com/www.iqworldinc.com/

and when i enter a subpage like 
http://www.etilerprep2go.com/egitimlerimiz-etiler-ingilizce-kursu/  it goes without any forwarding.